# Spotlight crashed; how to see what caused the crash?

Tags: macos

I managed to save the ~600 line log when Spotlight crashed:

```
Process:               Spotlight [379]
Path:                  /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight
Identifier:            com.apple.Spotlight
Version:               1.0 (1075.40)
Build Info:            SpotlightUI-1075040000000000~124
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Spotlight [379]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-01-04 23:56:11.119 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.5 (16F2073)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        6<redacted>7

Sleep/Wake UUID:       9<redacted>C

Time Awake Since Boot: 37000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        7  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x20:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010dc51000-000000010dcd6000 [  532K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd7798bb4 probeGC + 350
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd7798d37 -[NSConcreteMapTable setObject:forKey:] + 66
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd39b5188 _NXSetTrackingRect + 863
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd39b4e14 _NSSetTrackingRect + 665
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd3dea3a0 -[NSWindow(NSTrackingAreas) _didInstallTrackingRect:assumeInside:userData:trackingNum:] + 237
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd3930aa9 _setTrackingRect + 288
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd3dea7e6 -[NSWindow(NSTrackingAreas) _setTrackingRect:inside:owner:userData:useTrackingNum:install:] + 587
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd3deabf1 -[NSWindow(NSTrackingAreas) _setTrackingRect:inside:owner:userData:useTrackingNum:] + 64
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd3930698 -[NSView(NSInternal) _installTrackingArea:] + 422
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd393025a -[NSView(NSInternal) _enableTrackingArea:] + 102
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd392ffef -[NSView(NSInternal) _enableOrDisableTrackingAreas] + 240
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd392fed5 -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] + 542
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd392fdf5 -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] + 318
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd392fdf5 -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] + 318
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd392fc2c -[NSControl _windowChangedKeyState] + 49
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd392fdf5 -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] + 318
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd39c23b5 -[NSVisualEffectView _windowChangedKeyState] + 47
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd392fdf5 -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] + 318
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd392fdf5 -[NSView _windowChangedKeyState] + 318
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd39c1a9c +[NSWindow _enableKeyStateChangeNotifications] + 355
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd39bade7 -[NSWindow _changeKeyAndMainLimitedOK:] + 1263
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd3a77c59 -[NSWindow _makeKeyRegardlessOfVisibility] + 102
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd39bdd48 NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange + 147
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd3a77b97 -[NSWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:] + 91
24  com.apple.Spotlight             0x000000010dc97f9e 0x10dc51000 + 290718
25  com.apple.Spotlight             0x000000010dc83b06 0x10dc51000 + 207622
26  com.apple.Spotlight             0x000000010dc83f22 0x10dc51000 + 208674
27  com.apple.Spotlight             0x000000010dc8402f 0x10dc51000 + 208943
28  com.apple.Spotlight             0x000000010dca4596 0x10dc51000 + 341398
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffeb4dd524 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffeb4d48fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffeb4e1aac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 925
32  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5dcfbc9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
33  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d90c0d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
34  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d90114 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
35  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffd52f1ebc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
36  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffd52f1cf1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
37  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffd52f1b26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
38  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd388aa54 _DPSNextEvent + 1120
39  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd40067ee -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796
40  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd387f3db -[NSApplication run] + 926
41  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd3849e0e NSApplicationMain + 1237
42  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffeb50a235 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeb63134a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeb630797 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d91434 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d908c1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d90114 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd77a34e2 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 277
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd7833a55 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 111
7   com.apple.Spotlight             0x000000010dc94a45 0x10dc51000 + 277061
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd77b3b3d __NSThread__start__ + 1243
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb72393b _pthread_body + 180
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb723887 _pthread_start + 286
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb72308d thread_start + 13

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeb63134a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeb630797 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d91434 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d908c1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d90114 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fffd4ece734 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 313
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffd77b3b3d __NSThread__start__ + 1243
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb72393b _pthread_body + 180
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb723887 _pthread_start + 286
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb72308d thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeb63134a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeb630797 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d91434 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d908c1 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffd5d90114 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffd39d7f02 _NSEventThread + 205
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb72393b _pthread_body + 180
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb723887 _pthread_start + 286
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb72308d thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.coreanimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeb63134a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffeb630797 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffdb971bf0 CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 272
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fffdba223af thread_fun + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb72393b _pthread_body + 180
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb723887 _pthread_start + 286
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb72308d thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb723070 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x7fffffff7fffffff 0 + 9223372034707292159

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb723070 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x0000007265735573 0 + 491328329075

Thread 7 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fffeac16f31 objc_retain + 33
1   com.apple.Parsec                0x00007fffe5f4de45 -[PRSSearchSession cepDictionary] + 63
2   com.apple.ParsecUI              0x00007fffe5fac2e9 -[SPKCoreParsecInterface getCEPDataWithReply:] + 62
3   com.apple.ParsecUI              0x00007fffe5f8f39a +[SPKParsecQuery getCEPData] + 31
4   com.apple.Spotlight             0x000000010dc98078 0x10dc51000 + 290936
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffeb4dd524 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffeb4d48fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffeb4d686e _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 917
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffeb4d648c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb7235a2 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb72307d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffeb723070 start_wqthread + 0
1   ???                             0x00007000022d7b70 0 + 123145338846064

Thread 7 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000001  rbx: 0x00006100001ab7c0  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x061dfffff3518d55
  rdi: 0x00006100002ed000  rsi: 0x00007fffe5fe9c56  rbp: 0x0000700002254da0  rsp: 0x0000700002254da0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000002710  r10: 0x00007ffff3518d50  r11: 0x00007f8ce7007b60
  r12: 0x00007ffff351c9e0  r13: 0x00007ffff351c9e0  r14: 0x00007fffeac17040  r15: 0x00007fffe5fe9d79
  rip: 0x00007fffeac16f31  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000020

Logical CPU:     6
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Binary images removed, full text at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tx1sHHhu1UgeyPKvkSQEHv18wvzsdhrI/view?usp=sharing

How do I go about investigating what caused the crash?

Comment: @user Removing the entire log means the question is useless if the link ever breaks, so keep the important bits in the question body